# C sending char's via uart

Tags: c, serial-port

I have problmes with sending a few chars via serial port,

my sending procedure looks like

```
SendBlock(serial_port, OutputData, sizeof(OutputData))
```

When `OutputData = "ex text"` it works, i get received this text. but when im trying to send result of calculations ie `unsigned char output[32]`, for ex `output = ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb76` , but im receiving `aĆrY3ŁđbďÝ` i think terminal trying convert `ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb76` to asci, no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

This post [here](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/uart.html) implements quick and clean UART transfer of a few chars at a time. It might be useful for your application.

```
int main(void)
{

    char t[8] = "ex text"
    uart_init(BAUD_RATE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        if (uart_available()) {
            uart_putchar(t[i]);
        }
    }
}
```